# What's the proper way to retry commands in an AWS CFN template?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Sometimes commands like `apt-get update -q` fail randomly in a cloudformation template user-data script. What's the proper way to retry them till they succeed?

Comment: `until apt-get update -q ; do sleep 10 ; done` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, what's what I'm doing at the moment, doesn't feel right to add this to many commands

Comment: I don't see any way around it, unless you're willing to lose the granularity of having only failing jobs loop until finished. You could script of, for example 10 commands, run the whole thing, and then have a way of testing that there were no errors. Redirect master script output to log file and grep for 'ERROR" ? And thnen how do you decide which to rerun OR waste the time to rerun all 10 again. Will be happy to be proved wrong. What about Hadoop or ther parallel processor (gnu-parallel?)? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @shellter pointed out:

```
while ! apt-get update -q ; do sleep 1; done
```

Or, for a script:

```
while ! apt-get update -q
do
    echo "Failed. Trying again..." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```